# Is my If condition correct or not about the SESSION

Tags: php, session-variables, static-classes

When I open WAMP, it opens the index.php file which redirects me to `layout.php`, which is the first page. I  created an `if` condition on it to check if someone logged in, so that it displays the name of the user instead of the connexion/inscription text. Aside from that, nothing else changes.

**Layout.php**

```
<div class="header">
 <div class="header-left">
 <?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {?>
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="?controller=user&action=inscription">Inscription</a></li>
    <li class="login">
      <div id="loginContainer"><a id="loginButton"><span>Se Connecter</span></a>
        <div id="loginBox" style="display: none;">                
          <form id="loginForm"  method="POST" action="?controller=user&action=authentification">
            <fieldset id="body">
              <fieldset>
                <label>Login</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" id="email" >
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
              </fieldset>
              <input type="submit" id="login" value="Connexion" name="xxl1">
              <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> <i>Rester Connecté</i></label>
            </fieldset>
            <span><a href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a></span>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 <?php } else { $name = $_SESSION['login'] ?>
  <h1  style="
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-right: -11px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  "> Bonjour <?php echo $name?> </h1>
  <a href="?controller=login&action=profil" style="
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-right: -11px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  "> Editer mon profil </a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_GET['controller']) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $controller = $_GET['controller'];
    $action     = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $controller = 'accueil';
    $action     = 'home';
}

require_once('views/layout.php');
?>
```

Here is my Model with the Connexion function

**Users.php**

```
    public static function Connex()
    {
      if(isset($_POST['xxl1']))
      {
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $login=$_POST['login'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $requser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ? AND motdepasse = ?");
        $requser->execute(array($login,$password));
        $userexist = $requser->rowCount();
        if($userexist == 1)
        {
          session_start();
         $userinfo = $requser->fetch();
         $_SESSION['login'] = $userinfo['login'];
         $_SESSION['id_user'] = $userinfo['id_user'];
         $_SESSION['motdepasse'] = $userinfo['motdepasse'];
         if($userinfo['role']=="admin")
         {
           echo "TEST 1 "; 
         }
         else if($userinfo['role']=="client")
         {
        echo "TEST 2"; 
         }

       }
     }
   }
```

**User_controller.php**

```
<?php
Class UserController
{
    public function inscription()
    {

        $client = User::ajoutClient();
        require_once('views/users/inscription.php');

    }
    public function authentification()
    {

        $client = User::Connex();
        require_once('views/layout.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a session_start in layout.php as well.

Comment: Did you add a `session_start()` on the top?

Comment: It's logic is true, only you are missing semicolon at the end of $name = $_SESSION['login']    - what is the question by the way? Any problems with code?

Comment: when i put session_start there he will tell me that a session already started

Comment: Never store plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: i want to know if my logic is correct or not i mean i want to know if i can redirect in the same page after login in that's what i wanted to know

Comment: "i want to know if i can redirect in the same page". I can't see any redirection headers.

Comment: it's the require_once wich will take me there

Comment: unless there's a redirect header line inside those files referenced by the require_once, then no redirection occurs. You simply display different content. Technically, that's not a redirect. It's best to be clear about the terminology, so as to avoid confusion when discussing these things. The distinction is important here, because causing an actual redirect would cease the current PHP script execution and start a new one at the redirected URL.

Comment: now ive got a new problem , when i put session_start() in the first of the layout.php page i don't know from he recognize my login while i didn't even log in that's making me crazy  i have no idea from where he is filling the SESSION_['login'] variable